# Test whether point belongs to the region between contour lines in ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting

A simple question but, unfortunately, I could not find the answer.
Suppose I have a ListContourPlot built from some data set, e.g.,

```
plot = ListContourPlot[RandomReal[1, {50, 3}], ContourLabels -> All];
Show[plot, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0.5, 0.5}]}]]
```

[image: ListContourPlot example]

I need to be able to determine whether a particular point lies within a given range on this contour plot. For example, I want to check if the red point with coordinates `{0.5,0.5}` on my contour plot would fall between the contour lines `0.4` and `0.6`. Notice that this point is not necessarily a part of the original data set used to make the plot.
Just a True/False result of such a test would do.

Answer (score 2):

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {50, 3}];
plot = ListContourPlot[pts, ContourLabels -> All];
Show[plot, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0.5, 0.5}]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ip = Interpolation[pts, InterpolationOrder -> All];

0.4 < ip[0.5, 0.5] < 0.6
```

> False

Comment: thanks! that's much simpler than I thought.